# Extract variable names from string of regression formula

Tags: r, string, regression, brms

Context - I have a custom function (for workflow control reasons) that wraps a regression (in this case, using `brms`, but I don't think the question is specific to that). Something like this:

```
model_predict <- function(.data, dep_var, model, <args>) {
  ## Fit regression model to data
  fit <- brm(str_glue("{dep_var} ~ {model}"), .data)
  ...
}
```

The function argument `model` is a string version of a standard R regression model specification, and the argument `dep_var` is likewise a string version of the dependent variable name, so for instance:

```
dep_var <- "Y"
model <- "A + B + C + A*B"
```

Would yield the regression `Y ~ A + B + C + A*B`. This works fine for my purposes.

Here's my question - is there an easy way to extract the variable names from the `model` string? Consider a function `func` such that `func(model)` with `model` above would yield either `A, B, C` or `"A", "B", "C"` (either one could work for my purposes) - does such a function exist? Or is my best bet to make a custom function with string parsing?

Answer (score 0):

`all.vars` is your friend. Apply it on the `formula`, first element is the dependent variable so use `[-1]`. Either apply on the formula stored in the `"bmrsfit"` object,

```
library(brms)

model_predict <- function(.data, dep_var, model, args=NULL) {
  fo <- as.formula(paste(dep_var, '~', model))
  fit <- brm(formula=fo, data=.data)
  vn <- all.vars(fit$formula$formula)[-1]
  attr(fit, 'variable_names') <- vn
  return(fit)
}

res <- model_predict(.data=epilepsy, dep_var='count', model='zAge + zBase * Trt + (1|patient)')

attr(res, 'variable_names')
# [1] "zAge"    "zBase"   "Trt"     "patient"
```

or directly on the formula you create beforehand `all.vars(fo)[-1]`, so the model has not necessarily be estimated.

```
model_predict2 <- function(.data, dep_var, model, args=NULL) {
  fo <- as.formula(paste(dep_var, '~', model))
  # fit <- brm(formula=fo, data=.data)
  # vn <- all.vars(fit$formula$formula)[-1]
  # attr(fit, 'variable_names') <- vn
  # return(fit)
  return(all.vars(fo)[-1])
}

model_predict2(.data=epilepsy, dep_var='count', model='zAge + zBase * Trt + (1|patient)')
# [1] "zAge"    "zBase"   "Trt"     "patient"
```

Note that there is `reformulate` which you also might want to consider. It allows you to provide IVs and DV as vectors.

```
reformulate(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A*B'), 'Y')
# Y ~ A + B + C + A * B
```